# Vert.x Future/Promise Handler not called in Groovy

Tags: groovy, vert.x, vertx-verticle

I got a pretty small Verticle that should connect to a database and regularly poll a table and send the objects to the event bus. Thus far I can connect to the database, but the handler afterwards gets not executed and my polling timer does not start. I guess it's something obvious and appreciate every help.

I use Vert.x 3.8 Promises [as Futures are deprecated](https://github.com/vert-x3/wiki/wiki/3.8.0-Deprecations-and-breaking-changes#future-creation-and-completion) (just like in the example behind that link). As you can see in my code, using deprecated Futures *works just fine*! But who want's to use deprecated code, heh? Either I'm doing something wrong or that's a bug in Vert.x, what I don't assume.

My Vert.x is at 3.8.1

```
class JdbcVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {

    private SQLConnection connection

    @Override
    void start(Promise<Void> startPromise) {
        def jdbcParams = config().getJsonObject('connection')
        // This gets executed:
        testFuture().handler = { println "Test Future handler runs!" }

        // This is never executed :-(
        connect(jdbcParams).handler = { println "Connected..." }
    }

    Future<Void> connect(JsonObject jdbcParams) {
        def promise = Promise.<Void>promise()
        def client = JDBCClient.createShared(vertx, jdbcParams)

        client.getConnection() { connection ->
            if(connection.failed()) {
                promise.fail(connection.cause())
            } else {
                this.connection = connection.result()
                promise.complete()
            }
        }

        return promise.future()
    }

    Future<Void> testFuture() {
        def future = Future.<Void>future()
        vertx.setTimer(200) { future.complete() }
        return future
    }
}
```

Comment: why your `connect()` returns a Future instead of Promise?

Comment: Are you sure it's connecting? Is the handler for the future called at all? Is it called with `failed()` set to return true?

Comment: @injecteer because Future is the readers side of the Promise [as of Vert.x 3.8](https://github.com/vert-x3/wiki/wiki/3.8.0-Deprecations-and-breaking-changes#future-creation-and-completion)

Comment: @tim_yates pretty sure, since a simple `println` statement in the `client.getConnection()` is executed. Either way, `failed()` or `complete()`, the handler should be called.

Comment: I agree the handler should be called, but if it's `failed()`, the return will prevent you reaching your println marked by `// This is never executed :-(`

Comment: @tim_yates you are right and I stripped down my code to show, that the problem is but before.